# which framework is used for twitter application

Tags: java, php, javascript, frameworks

Which framework does twitter used during application development? 
or is that build without any framework?

in general how to identify which framework is been used for development of such huge portal

Comment: if you use firefox there is a addon that can be used to know the current website opened used javascript files called Jsview 

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsview/

its helpful to know what the website used frameworks,libraries

Answer (score 3):

http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/04/twitter-search-is-now-3x-faster_1656.html

> Last week, [as of April 6, 2011] we launched a replacement for our Ruby-on-Rails front-end: a Java server we call Blender.

---

Twitter used to use Ruby On Rails. This environment is good for rapid development of say a new site.  Java tends to be better for more mature applications.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails found by using Google ;)

> Rails running on Matz's Ruby Interpreter (the de facto reference interpreter for Ruby) had been criticized for issues with scalability.[25] These critics often mentioned various Twitter outages in 2007 and 2008, which spurred Twitter's partial transition to Scala (which runs on the Java Virtual Machine) for their queuing system and other middleware.[26][27] The user interface aspects of the site continue to run Ruby on Rails.[28]

For popular sites, I would try Googling to find information about them.

Comment: Nope, not valid anymore. Twitter is nowadays fully JVM-based.

Comment: Here's a relevant link: http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/04/twitter-search-is-now-3x-faster_1656.html